# Is @Component+router-outlet the only way to have reusable template in Angular 7?

Tags: angular, angular7

I've followed official tutorial (https://angular.io/guide/router) on Routing and few other sources and I am unsure if @Component is proper approach for simple templating.

My goal was to have a search-bar component which I can place for example on landing page as 1st section, then when user is not on landing page - place it in header, and maybe even elsewhere. Basically stand-alone thing that just works on its own anywhere.

There is this tutorial app https://stackblitz.com/angular/empolopovbx
where they use named `router outlets` to create outlet named `popup` that will contain component for creating `crisis message`. Now it is all fine, but whole mechanic works basically like opening 2 pages (refering to Angular's `routes/components`) and placing one in main (unnamed) outlet and second (crisis message) in said `popup` outlet.

This translates to links such as this:

- site/superheroes(popup:compose)

**So for every named router outlet I'd get (router-outlet-name:component) in link.**

Then I thought - is this really a way to go when I have several outlets in parent-components and want to reuse arbitrary number of components across whole app? Since I am pretty much still new to Angular this just bothers me - am I misunderstanding usage of named router outlets? Should they even be used in "high numbers"? For example page like this:

`app.component`:

```
<header>...</header>
<router-outlet>
<footer>...</footer>
```

`landing.component`:

```
<section class="landing-swiper">
    ...
</section>
<section class="landing-search">
    <router-outlet name="search-bar">
<section>
<section class="landing-news">
    <router-outlet name="news-window">
<section>
<section class="landing-contact">
    <router-outlet name="contact-form">
<section>
```

So basically `app.component` is the main one giving us header and footer and I want to have landing page (`landing.component`) inserted as a content into it.

But then `landing.component` also uses few others (which can also be used in other places, for example `contact.component` which here would be inserted to router `contact-form`, would also be placed in "About Company" page).

So question here is - do I understand architecture correctly, **is it normal that I will get those long links when I use many router-outlets**?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure of your exact requirements, but it sounds like you should not be using router outlets in this situation.

Router outlets are meant for when a "parent" component has several "child" components, and would like to show one at a time, and the one that it shows depends on the route.

I think it's pretty unusual to have more than two levels of routing in an Angular app. Possible, but very unusual.

This is usually only used when the child component represents a sub-section of the application, and there are multiple such sub-sections that get displayed in that one spot at different times.

If all you want is to have one component display inside another, then you should just place an html tag in the parent's template that uses the child component's "selector"

So, for instance, where you have

```
<section class="landing-search">
    <router-outlet name="search-bar">
<section>
```

i'm guessing that you will always be showing your search bar component there, and not swapping out different search bar components.

In that case, if your search bar component's selector is, e.g. 'landing-search-bar', then you would use:

```
<section class="landing-search">
    <landing-search-bar></landing-search-bar>
<section>
```

Comment: This is very helpful. I got ahead of myself, forgot basics, and tried doing it with Router instead of template syntax which I now remember reading earlier (basics xD). So now my question is - does inserting @Component in such manner (with it's tag) preserves its functionality (entire, like it would work with Router)? I guess yes and will check it out, but "yes/no" answer is never bad. Thank you.

Comment: Yes, it does, unless of course, it's injecting the Router and looking for the current route.